# Как получить название функции, которая выполняется в текущий момент в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Как можно получить название функции, которая начала выполняться в коде python внутри самой функции, при этом заранее не написав и не выведя название внутри этой же функции.

Пример:

```
def tester(*args, **kwargs):
    # тут какой-то код должен вывести названии этой функции
```

Плохой пример:

```
def tester(*args, **kwargs):
    print('Сейчас работает функция tester')
```

Почему я не могу передавать название функции внутри самой функции, для её вывода? - Я могу много раз изменять названия своих функций, соответственно и названия внутри функций мне столько же раз придется изменять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно написать декоратор и применять к функциям которые Вы хотитe логировать (выводить можно не только имя но и аргументы). Пример:

```
from functools import wraps


def func_name_logger(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f.__name__)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorator

@func_name_logger
def any_functions():
    print('start work.')

any_functions() # output: any_functions
                #         start work.
```

Еще один вариант, модуль `inspect`. Пример:

```
import inspect

LAST_FUNC = None


def foo():
    global LAST_FUNC
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    LAST_FUNC = inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function

foo()
print(LAST_FUNC)  # foo
```

Comment: а что если мне необходимо не просто отобразить результат, а присвоить его ещё в переменную?

Comment: @MaximChyorny дополнил ответ, но лучше изначально описывать требуемую задачу полностью.

Comment: кратко и полезно, благодарю